# Question on SQLite database query on INNER join

Tags: android-sqlite

I'm new for SQLite DB, I have three tables, M_Clinic, M_Healees and T_Treatments.. In following query, I have used two inner joins from T_Treatments (Transaction) to two of the master refernce tables M_Clinic and M_Healees.. There is a record on both T_Treatments and M_Healees with Healee_ID column with data value 1. However for some reason it is not pulling the record out.. If I do the same query without "where T_Treatments.Healee_ID = 1", the query pulls out the record.. Am I missing anything?

```
select   M_Healees.Healee_ID,
  M_Healees.Name,
  M_Healees.PhoneNumber,
  M_Healees.HealthInformation,
  M_Healees.Address,
  M_Healees.Clinic_ID,
  M_Clinic.Name,
  M_Clinic.Address,
  T_Treatments.TreatmentDate,
  T_Treatments.Symptoms,
  T_Treatments.ACUPoint
from  T_Treatments
INNER JOIN M_Clinic ON M_Healees. Clinic_ID = M_Clinic. Clinic_ID
INNER JOIN M_Healees  ON M_Healees.Healee_ID = T_Treatments.Healee_ID
where T_Treatments.Healee_ID = 1
```

These are the data on my tables:

TABLE : M_clinic

```
<table><tr><td>Clinic_ID|</td><td>Name|</td><td>Address|</td></tr>
<tr><td>PK|</td><td>Salem Clinic|</td><td>No.52, Seerangan Street-2, Dhadhagapatti gate, Salem|</td></tr>
</table>
```

TABLE : M_Healees

```
<table><tr><td>Healee_ID|</td><td>Name|</td><td>PhoneNumber|</td><td>HealthInformation|</td><td>Address|</td><td>Clinic_ID|</td></tr>
<tr><td>1|</td><td>Narmada|</td><td>9988|</td><td>Body Pains|</td><td>Nethimedu|</td><td>PK|</td></tr>
</table>
```

TABLE : M_Treatments

```
<table><tr><td>Healee_ID|</td><td>TreatmentDate|</td><td>Symptoms|</td><td>ACUPoint|</td></tr>
<tr><td>1|</td><td>10/08/2019|</td><td>Body Pain|</td><td>LU5|</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your query works fine. Did you misspell the name of the table T_Treatments instead of M_Treatments? See this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oonTumk8dcp6WraLeP7cBu/1

Comment: Thanks for your help friend... No misspell, but if I use "where T_Treatments.Healee_ID = 1" it is not fetching, however if I use "where M_Healees.Healee_ID = 1".. Then it fetches..